# How to edit/add two columns to a dataframe in pandas at once - df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, apply

So I've been doing things like this with pandas:

```
usrdata['columnA'] = usrdata.apply(functionA, axis=1)
```

in order to do row operations and changing/adding columns to my dataframe.
However, now I want to try to do something like this:

```
usrdata['columnB', 'columnC'] = usrdata.apply(functionB, axis=1)
```

But the output of function B is a Series with only one column in a tuple (with two values for each row) apparently. Is there a nice way for me to either:

1. format the output from functionB so it can readily be added to my
   dataframe
2. add (and possibly have to unpack) the output from functionB and assign each each column to each column of my dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `zip`:

```
usrdata['columnB'], usrdata['columnC'] = zip(*usrdata.apply(functionB, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assign directly to a df consisting of your new df's and modify the func body to return a Series constructed with a list of the data:

```
In [9]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df
Out[9]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
In [10]:

def func(x):
    return pd.Series([x*3, x*10])
​
df[['b','c']] = df['a'].apply(func)
df
Out[10]:
   a   b   c
0  1   3  10
1  2   6  20
2  3   9  30
3  4  12  40
4  5  15  50
```